# Firebase: Disabling/Deleting Trial Authenticated User

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to disable authenticated user in timely matter like trial version for a certain days or hours? Is it possible to do it programmatically? If i'm not mistaken, I can't find a settings within Firebase Authentication Console..

Answer (score 0):

When you hover over a use in the Firebase Auth panel of the Firebase Console, you can see an overflow menu. That menu contains the option to disable the user's account:

[image: Firebase Auth panel showing menu option to disable user account]

This will prevent the user from logging in in the future. It will not immediately disable their access to the app, since their current access token may still be valid for up to an hour. If you want to immediately prevent the user from accessing your app, you'll also want to implement a secondary authorization mechanism, such as keeping a list of banned users in the Firebase Database.